# Python interpretor returns error for FASTAPI - **extra: Any,

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm having trouble executing fastapi under WSL.
I'm using:

- WSL2
- Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
- Python 3.5.2 (using Visual Studio Code interpretor)
- fastapi - 0.73.0
- uvicorn - 0.8.6

I'm getting an error when I execute the `uvicorn` command -

> **extra: Any,

- see attached image.

I'm stuck on this for a while so any ideas would be strongly appreciated.

I tried updating python interpretor to newer version (3.9) but for some reason I did not succeed - see pls the second attached screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: FastAPI requires python 3.6 and won't work with Python 3.5 as you've found out. The ubuntu version you're using does not have a new enough Python version. You can either install a more recent Python version in Windows, upgrade your Ubuntu version or use the deadsnakes ppa: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh I'll try that asap

Comment: Just updating Ubuntu to 18.x solved my issues. Now fastapi and uvicorn[standard] are properly installed and up-and-running. I can consider your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastAPI requires python 3.6 and won't work with Python 3.5 as you've found out.

The ubuntu version you're using does not have a new enough Python version by default. You can either install a more recent Python version in Windows, upgrade your Ubuntu version [or use the deadsnakes ppa](http://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to get access to newer versions of Python on older Ubuntu versions (or the other way around if you need old Python versions on more recent versions of Ubuntu).